# updatedTransactions first time, call old queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Firs time i tried to make a subscription this function call for all transactions, but after then if i tried to subscribe it calls just 1 state.
This code same as in apple developer documentation

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
             switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"purchasing in progress");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                NSLog(@"Stade deferred");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"State failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"Sucsess purchased");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"restored");
                break;
            default:
                // For debugging
                NSLog(@"Unexpected transaction state %@",@(transaction.transactionState));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

updatedTransactions is called only for updated transactions (see Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/)

transactions - An array of the transactions that were updated.

But on application start or first purchase iOS sends every transaction from SKPaymentQueue: defaultQueue.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html: 
Terminate and relaunch your app. Store Kit calls the paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method again shortly after launch; this time, let your app respond normally. Verify that your app correctly delivers the product and completes the transaction

So if app should view all transactions, it should request SKPaymentQueue: defaultQueue.